# Materialize CSS Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I have implemented the Materialize CSS modal in the following way, but it does not work.

```
ERROR:

    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (ordine.php:70)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal').modal();
});
```

```html
  <!--MODAL -->
  <a class='waves-effect waves-light btn blue modal-trigger' href='#modal1'><i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i></a>
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- MONDAL -->
```

Comment: As a side note - jQuery is no longer a dependency for Materialize. So you can save yourself a whole bunch of KB and use the javascript init instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an error *$ is not defined*. This error says that jQuery isn't defined.

You must include it, here's the CDN

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4t25mdba/1/

Comment: thank you. is it possible that the error is due to the order in which I included the css, js and jquery?

Comment: it might ! Be sure to link the css in the head. The jquery script import must be referenced first then the material design library right before the </body>